# Exposing state props from functional component to navigationOptions function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, expo

I have a component that renders the input field, I want to pass the data to the next page when user clicks on "next" button in the header. What is the best practice for doing so? How do I expose this into `Page.navigationOptions`?

Or is it best to just set up redux for these types of things?

```
const Page = () => {
  const [desc, getDesc] = useState('');

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputFieldDescContainer}>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder='Write a description...'
        onChangeText={(text) => getDesc(text)}
        value={desc}
      />
    </View>  
  );
};

// How do I pass desc properties down into navigationOptions?

Page.navigationOptions = (navData) => {
  return {
    headerTitle: 'Page,
    headerRight: (
      <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
        <Item
          title='Next'
          onPress={() => {
            navData.navigation.navigate('NextPage', {data: navData});
          }}
        />
      </HeaderButtons>
    ),
    headerBackTitle: null
  };
};

/* NextPage.js */

const NextPage = (props) => {
  console.log('enter props data', props.navigation.getParam('data'));
  console.log('enter props navigation', props.navigation);
  const [valueText, setValueText] = useState();
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => setValueText(text)} value={valueText}/>
      <TouchableOpacity><Text>Create your workout</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing state and props between component and options is possible in React Navigation 5 https://blog.expo.io/announcing-react-navigation-5-0-bd9e5d45569e

In React Navigation 4, you can use params to store the value to be able to share it:

```js
const Page = ({ navigation }) => {
  const desc = navigation.getParam('description', '');

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputFieldDescContainer}>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder='Write a description...'
        onChangeText={(text) => navigation.setParams({ description: text )}
        value={desc}
      />
    </View>  
  );
}
```